# Theoretical limit of file descriptors in Linux

Tags: linux, ram, file-descriptor

I'm running a dedicated proxy server with Squid, and I'm trying to get a feel for the maximum number of connections that the server can handle. I've realized this comes down to available file descriptors on the Linux machine.

I've found plenty of information on increasing maximum file descriptors, but I'd like to find out the theoretical maximum. According to the StackOverflow question ["Why do operating systems limit file descriptors?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798365/why-do-operating-systems-limit-file-descriptors), it comes down to available system RAM, which makes plenty of sense.

Now, given how much RAM I have available, how can I determine a maximum value for file descriptors for the operating system? Some value which would obviously still allow the system to run stably.

Perhaps someone might have an idea given other high-end production servers? What is the 'norm' for maxing out the potential number of simultaneous connections (file descriptors)? Any insight into how I can max-out file descriptors for a Linux system would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have other resource problems before you run out of descriptors.

Answer (score 3):

You have many limits.

- Multiplexing. This shouldn't be an issue if your application uses a decent backend. [Libev](http://libev.schmorp.de/bench.html) claims to multiplex with 350us latency at 100,000 file descriptors.
- Application speed. A 1ms application latency at that scale (pretty low) per request would take almost two minutes to serve 100,000 requests in optimum conditions.
- Bandwidth. Depending on your application and protocol efficiency, this may be a problem. You say it's a squid proxy... if you're proxying websites: a client with no cache requesting a website can receive anywhere from a few hundred KB to several MB. If your average full page request per client was 500KB, you'd max out a full gigabit connection at 2000 requests per second. This might be your limiting factor.

2000 file descriptors is a fairly small amount. I've seen simple apps in languages like Python scale to over 3000 active connections on a single processor core without bad latency.

You can test your squid proxy with software like apachebench running on multiple client computers to get some realistic numbers. It's pretty easy to crank your file descriptor limit up to 2000+ and see what happens, and whether it even makes a difference afterwards.