# What are the cons if I set the file descriptor limit to a huge number?

Tags: python, linux, macos, tornado

I use Tornado(a python framework) to develope websites, but it often pops me the `OSError - too many open files` error during high concurrency tests.

One way to solve this is to set the FD limit to a higher number.

What are the cons, or disadvantages of setting a high FD limit? Can I set it arbitrarily to, like 99999999?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good reference about what are the limitations, and how it affect your system.

[Theoretical limit of file descriptors in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677488/theoretical-limit-of-file-descriptors-in-linux)

Comment: I like this answer because the link did explain the limits and expenses of an FD.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to set it quite high. Usually the default for desktop OS is quite low. The main disadvantage is the extra memory that is allocated

Comment: "Extra memory that is allocated" - allocated by what? I'm not aware of anything that allocates memory based on ulimits.

Comment: Who said anything about ulimit? The real limit is file-max