# Can I prevent ZeroMQ from occupying file descriptors?

Tags: zeromq, file-descriptor, distributed-system

I have a setup where a master process is setting up a **`ZMQ_ROUTER`** and then forks many child processes, which then connect to that router.

Whenever a child `zmq_connect()`'s to the master, one file descriptor is occupied.

This however limits the number of interacting processes to the number of allowed file descriptors ( per process ). For me ( linux ), this currently is just 1024.

That is way too small for my intended use ( a multi-agent / swarm simulation ).

---

**Answer**:

You can't, except when using an inter-thread socket type ( using an `inproc://` transport-class ). All other protocols use one file descriptor per connection.

One new approach to reduce the number of necessary file descriptors per application, if that application has several services ( e.g. several `tcp://<address:port>` connections can be made to ), seems to be to use the resource property [resource property](http://zmtp.org/page:read-the-docs#toc18), which allows one to combine several services to one endpoint.

Comment: Sounds attractive to have message-passing intelligent swarm. Anyway, alex, the direction goes into double-trouble, with the pain coming from both **`PTIME` & `PSPACE`** directions in the `ZMQ_FD` sense and potentially the `EXPTIME` horror may come from the messaging flow -- **what is the order of magnitude of your target numbers?** `1E4`? `1E5`? `1E6`? Will love to hear about your Project / Research more, alex.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the fact that splitting a given task into a multi-agent thing may increase complexity. I heard arguments in both directions; Some people say 'we need to split it up, otherwise we can't get a flexible/capable enough solution', others say: 'bring it together otherwise you can't control complexity'. I guess both is true. Depends on the application.

Comment: There was absolutely no objection on this per se, but need to know the projected orders of magnitude your swarms are going to grow into. **So?**

Comment: Ah, I missed this information. I would say 10k is a must 100k is good everything above would be great.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, **100k+ is nice and doable**and can keep growing, as a principally distributed-system, by further scaling, depending on how complex the swarm inter-agent signalling / communication layer ought be.

Answer (score 3):

### The Swarm first:

First of all, a smart solution of the massive herd of agents requires both **flexibility** ( in swarm framework design for features' additions ) and **efficiency** ( for both **scalability** and **speed** ) so as to achieve fastest possible simulation run-times, in spite of **`PTIME`** & **`PSPACE`** obstacles, with possible risk of wandering into **`EXPTIME`** zone in more complex inter-agent communication schemes.

---

### Efficiency next:

At the first moment, my guess was to rather use and customise a bit light-weight-er POSIX-based signalling/messaging framework [**`nanomsg`** -- a younger sister of `ZeroMQ` from Martin SUSTRIK, co-father of ZeroMQ](http://nanomsg.org/documentation-zeromq.html) -- where a **`Context()`**-less design plus additional features alike **`SURVEY`** and **`BUS`** messaging archetype are of particular attractivity for swarms with your own software-designed problem-domain-specific messaging/signalling protocols:
[image]

---

### 100k+ with `file_descriptor`s

Well, you need a courage. Doable, but sleeves up, it will require hands on efforts in kernel, tuning in system settings and you will pay for having such scale by increased overheads.

[Andrew Hacking has **explained** both the PROS and CONS of the "just" increasing `fd` count ( not only on the kernel side of the system tuning and configuration ).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25737274/3666197)

> Other factors to consider are that while some software may use **`sysconf(OPEN_MAX)`** to dynamically determine the number of files that may be open by a process, a lot of software still uses the **`C`** library's default **`FD_SETSIZE`**, **which is typically 1024 descriptors** and as such can never have more than that many files open regardless of any administratively defined higher limit.

[Andrew has also directed your kind attention to **this**, that may serve as an ultimate report on how to setup a **system for 100k-200k connections**.](https://rerepi.wordpress.com/2008/04/19/tuning-freebsd-sysoev-rit/)

---

### Do static scales above 100k per host make any real sense for swarm simulations?

While still "technically" doable, there are further limits -- even `nanomsg` will not be able to push more than about **`1.000.000 [MSGs/s]`** which is fairly well enough for most applications, that cannot keep the pace with this native speed of message-dispatch. Citations state some **`~6 [us]`** for CPU-core to CPU-core transfer latencies and if the user-designed swarm-processing application cannot make the sending loop under some **`3-4 [us]`** the performance ceiling is not anywhere close to cause an issue.

---

### How to scale above that?

A distributed multi-host processing is the first dimension to attack the static scale of the swarm. Next would be a need to introduce an RDMA-injection so as to escape from the performance bottleneck of any stack-processing in the implementation of the distributed messaging / signalling. Yes, **this can move your Swarm system into nanosecond-scale latencies zone, but at the cost of building an HPC / high-tech computing infrastructure** ( which would be a great Project, if your Project sponsor can adjust financing of such undertaking -- + pls. pls. do let me know if **yes**, would be more than keen to join such **swarm intelligence HPC-lab** ), but worth to know about this implication before deciding on architecture and knowing the ultimate limits is the key to do it well from the very beginning.